# finding all vertices on a negative cycle using belman ford twice

Tags: algorithms, graphs

We are given that the following algorithm finds the vertices inside a negative cycle and we need to show an example for it such that it fails.

```
for each  v in V
  dist[v] = inf+
dist[s] = 0
for i=1 to |V| - 1
  for each (u,v) in E
    relax(u,v,w)
for each v in V
  dist'[v] = dist[v]
for i=1 to |V|
  for each (u,v) in E
    relax(u,v,w)
A = {v:dist[v] != dist'[v]}
```

```
relax(u, v, w):
    if dist[v] > dist[u] + w(u, v):
        dist[v] = dist[u] + w(u, v)
        v.p = u
```

Can someone show me a graph with a negative cycle that will not bring the right result?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?  What task do you want to solve?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?